# Creating a file in program, mapping the file, and using memcpy... all permissions open, but error code is 'permission denied'?

Tags: c++, linux, mmap, memcpy

UPDATE: okay, the mapping did not succeed, and the `errno` I am getting says 'permission denied.' Given that the target file has all permissions 'on,' I am running out of ideas for what is causing the failure.

I'm trying to copy a 1GB file to a file that the program creates, and the page size of the virtual system is 4kB. I strictly only need a pointer to the output file to write to, but the only way I've found so far is to mmap() the output file as well. Instructions also said 'write the mapped data to an output file but not using a write() system call.' The input file part of the equation appears to work fine, but trying to write to the output gives segmentation faults. I think it has to be something to do with either how I am creating (or filling) the output file, or something wrong with the mmap() that maps the output file.

What I *think* I'm doing:

I create the output file and the user, group, and others should be able to read and write to it, the output should be wide open. I write a bunch of '-' to it so it's not a 0 byte file - I tried ftruncate and lseek, which worked but filled it with NULL characters.

I mmap the output file and doing a test with `cout << endl << "Target pointer " << target << endl;` results in a segfault (doing the same to the input file causes it to print the mapped characters). If I don't bother with the test, nothing comes up.

After printing out 'output mapping succeeded,' `memcpy(target, "testtext", sizeof("testtext")-1);` gets a segfault.

```
int main()
{
    int outfile = creat("outFile.txt", O_RDWR | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT | 
       S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);

    //check to see that outfile exists
    if (outfile < 0)
    {
        cout << "\n" << "output file cannot be opened, error" << "\n";
        cout << strerror(errno) << "\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    int pagesize = getpagesize();

    for (int i=0; i<pagesize; i++)
    {
        write(outfile, "-", 1);
    }

    char* target;

    target = (char*)mmap(NULL, pagesize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, outfile, 0);

    ///Did the mapping succeed ?
    if (target == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        cout << "\n" << "output mapping did not succeed" << "\n";
        cout << strerror(errno) << "\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\n" << "output mapping succeeded" << "\n";
    }

    memcpy(target, "testtext", sizeof("testtext") -1);

    munmap(target, pagesize);

    close(outfile);
    cout << "files closed" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Needs a [mcve], not scattered lines of code.

Comment: And why not mmap the entire file at once instead of a `pagesize` chunk?

Comment: Made minimal reproducible example, and the file to be copied is a 1GB file while only pagesize (4096 bytes) amount of data is being mapped to RAM.

Comment: You're only *asking* it to map `pagesize` bytes!  The second parameter to `mmap` is the length of the mapping you want.  If you pass `1073741824` you'll map a gigabyte.

Comment: Also, `mmap` is unusual in that on failure it doesn't return a null pointer, but rather a value equal to the macro `MAP_FAILED`.  So your error check doesn't work.

Comment: I was under the impression I would need to map it one page of bytes at a time, then copy a page of bytes, then repeat this until the whole file had been copied. Would just changing ```NULL``` in the error check to ```MAP_FAILED``` work?

Comment: No, no. You can map the entire file and let `mmap` worry about the memory behind the scenes. You will also need to nul-terminate the output file if you expect to output it's contents with `<<`.See also `man 2 sendfile` for another option. (limited to a 2G file-size there -- but blistering fast)

Comment: I'm not sure why you've chosen to memory map the file. If I was implementing this I'd just do a raw read (binary, not strings) into a large buffer. Say a 100 megabytes. Then I'd write it to the new file whatever number of bytes were read. Then when there are no more bytes left the file is copied and I'd close both. But I may be missing something.

Comment: It's a school project, we have to read all data from an input file and write it to an output file (created using creat() within the program) without using a plain write() system call. I don't know that sendfile() would be acccepted as not using a plain system call, and that the directions include a hint about 'use a combination of mmap and memcpy' and 'Also remember that the OS creates a backup of pages being modified in the memory.'